# Data Management in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, tidyr

So I have this code where I am trying to unite separate columns called grade prek-12 into one column called `Grade`. I have employed the `tidyr` package and used this line of code to perform said task:

```
unite(dta, "Grade",
          c(Gradeprek, 
            dta$Gradek, dta$Grade1, dta$Grade2,
            dta$Grade3, dta$Grade4, dta$Grade5,
            dta$Grade6, dta$Grade7, dta$Grade8,
            dta$Grade9, dta$Grade10, dta$Grade11,
            dta$Grade12),
      sep="")
```

However, I have been getting an error saying this:

> error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
>   The following do not: *  c(Gradeprek, dta$Gradek, dta$Grade1, dta$Grade2, dta$Grade3, dta$Grade4, dta$Grade5, dta$Grade6, ...

Penny for your thoughts on how I can resolve the situation.

Comment: What data frame does Gradeprek reference?

Comment: dta, sorry I forgot to inert that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing and matching the two syntax options for `unite` and `unite_` - you need to pick one and stick with it. In both cases, do not use `data$column` - they take a data argument so you don't need to re-specify which data frame your columns come from.

**Option 1: NSE** The default non-standard evaluation means bare column names - no quotes! And no `c()`.

```
unite(dta, Grade, Gradeprek, Gradek, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, ..., 
    Grade12, sep = "")
```

There are tricks you can do with this. For example, if all your `Grade` columns are in this order next to each other in your data frame, you could do

```
unite(dta, Grade, Gradeprek:Grade12, sep = "")
```

You could also use `starts_with("Grade")` to get all column that begin with that string. See `?unite` and its link to `?select` for more details.

**Option 2: Standard Evaluation** You can use `unite_()` for a standard-evaluating alternative which will expect column names in a character vector.  This has the advantage in this case of letting you use `paste()` to build column names in the order you want:

```
unite_(dta, col = "Grade", c("Gradeprek", "Gradek", paste0("Grade", 1:12)), sep = "")
```